# How to know is iPhone device have 3G network or Wifi network thorugh iPhone sdk?

Tags: networking, ios4

I want to know if my iPhone has a network connection. But what I didn't get is if the connction is Wifi or 3G thorugh SDK. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the model through the SDK.  You should be able to use that to find out the specs.

Edit: Expanding answer in response to comment

```
 #include "Reachability.h" 
 Reachability *reach = [[Reachability alloc]init];
```

AND THEN check the internetconnectionstatus.

Comment: Sir i am not able to get what you suggest is there any code to find out which network is avilable is 3G or Wifi?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  To check what type of connection is being used... 
#include "Reachability.h"

 Reachability *reach = [[Reachability alloc]init];   AND THEN check the internetconnectionstatus.